# Что сделать чтобы скрипт пересчитывал значение суммы в каждой форме, а не только в первой?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

Делаю лэнд. Есть 8 одинаковых форм отправки для каждого товара.
Ознакомится можно здесь http://prots.pro/portfolio/roses/

```
 <form class="rose-form8 rose-form form">
    <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
    <input type="hidden" class="rosename" name="rosename" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_content" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_campaign" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_term" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_medium" value="">
    <div class="form__wrapper">
      <div class="form__title">
        Ваш заказ:
      </div>
      <div class="cart__item">
        <div class="cart__item-img">
          <img src="./images/catalog-img-8.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="cart__item-name">
            Роза в колбе "King" Синяя
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="number">
          <span class="minus">-</span>
          <input class="count-input" name="count__input" type="text" value="1"/>
          <span class="plus">+</span>
        </div>
        <div class="cart__item-price" data-price="3100">
          3100 ₽
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="allcart__price">
        Сумма: <input readonly name="summ__input" type="text">₽
      </div>
      <div class="form__inner">
        <div class="input__wrapper">
          <div class="input__title">
            Ваше Имя:
          </div>
          <input type="text" name='name' class="text__input" placeholder="Ольга" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input__wrapper">
          <div class="input__title">
            Ваш телефон:
          </div>
          <input type="tel" name="tel" class="phone__input" placeholder="+7(999) 999-99-99" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input__wrapper">
          <div class="select">
            <select name="select__grav">
              <option>Выбрать гравировку</option>
              <option value="С Любовью...">С Любовью...</option>
              <option value="Я Тебя Люблю!">Я Тебя Люблю!</option>
              <option value="Ты Мой Ангел...">Ты Мой Ангел...</option>
              <option value="Любимой Маме!">Любимой Маме!</option>
              <option value="Ты Прекрасна!">Ты Прекрасна!</option>
              <option value="Любимой Дочери!">Любимой Дочери!</option>
              <option value="С Юбилеем!">С Юбилеем!</option>
              <option value="Моей Принцессе!">Моей Принцессе!</option>
              <option value="Самой Лучшей Маме!">Самой Лучшей Маме!</option>
              <option value="С Днём Рождения!">С Днём Рождения!</option>
              <option value="В Наш День...">В Наш День...</option>
              <option value="Любимой Подруге!">Любимой Подруге!</option>
              <option value="Самой Милой">Самой Милой</option>
              <option value="Красавице От Чудовища">Красавице От Чудовища</option>
              <option value="Любимой Супруге">Любимой Супруге</option>
              <option value="Любимой Сестре!">Любимой Сестре!</option>
              <option value="Ты Моё Всё!">Ты Моё Всё!</option>
              <option value="Любимой Бабуле!">Любимой Бабуле!</option>
              <option value="Моё Сердце Навеки Твоё!">Моё Сердце Навеки Твоё!</option>
              <option value="Самой Родной С Любовью!">Самой Родной С Любовью!</option>
            </select>
            <div class="select__arrow"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input__wrapper">
          <input type="text" name="address" class="text__input" placeholder="Адрес доставки" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input__wrapper">
          <div class="select">
            <select name="select__box">
              <option>Добавить WOW коробку 600 руб</option>
              <option value="Да">Да</option>
              <option value="Нет">Нет</option>
            </select>
            <div class="select__arrow"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input__wrapper">
          <label class="input-cb">Я даю согласие на обработку персональных данных
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="form__button btn" type="submit">Заказать звонок</button>
      <div class="close__btn"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Такой обработчик count input

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.minus').click(function () {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
    count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
    $input.val(count);
    $input.change();
    return false;
  });
  $('.plus').click(function () {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
    $input.change();
    return false;
  });
});
```

И вот такой js обработчик пересчета суммы(количество из +- инпута умножить на цену одной единицы товара из data-price).

```
$('.count-input').on('change', function(){
  let summ = $('.count-input').val() *  $('.cart__item-price').data('price');
  $('.allcart__price input').val(summ);
  $('.allcart__price input').attr('value', summ);
});

let summ = $('.count-input').val() *  $('.cart__item-price').data('price');
$('.allcart__price input').val(summ);
$('.allcart__price input').attr('value', summ);
```

Сейчас при открытии первой формы все работает ок, берется сумма из data-price умножается на число из count инпута и передается в .allcart__price input и в его value. Но это работает только для первой формы, во всех последующих формах пересчета не происходит вовсе. Что поменять чтобы этот пересчет значения сумы товара и его количества работал для каждой формы отдельно? Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.count-input').on('change', function(){
    let summ = parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($(this).closest('form.rose-form8').find('.cart__item-price').data('price'));
    $(this).closest('form.rose-form8').find('.allcart__price input').val(summ);
    $(this).closest('form.rose-form8').find('.allcart__price input').attr('value', summ);
  });
```

Comment: Поменял, проблема теперь в том что значение цены берется из первого .cart__item-price и при закрытие первой и открытии новой формы в новом форме уже стоит сумма общая с предыдущей формы....

Comment: А 2 строчки после той что я указал Вы поменяли, что бы они тоже работали локально для конкретной формы? Как то так - $(this).closest('.cart__item').find('.allcart__price input').val(summ);

Comment: теперь вовсе ничего не считает, счетчик количества работает, но сумма стоит на месте.

Comment: И еще проблема что не могу получить отдельный cart__item-price, всегда первая цена

Comment: Изменил код. Так должно быть, что бы работало для 1-ой конкретной формы

Comment: Заработало! Только теперь нюанс такой что начальная сумма(до увеличения количества) такая как в первой форме. Скорее всего изза этого куска который обявляет значение при прогрузке js файла.
let summ = $('.count-input').val() *  $('.cart__item-price').data('price');
$('.allcart__price input').val(summ);
$('.allcart__price input').attr('value', summ); 

 Как сделать чтобы при каждом открытии новой формы общая сумма считалась сразу для каждой формы.

Comment: типа как я понимаю значение берется из первого .cart__item-price, а нужно чтобы бралось в каждой форме для своего.

Comment: Этот кусок вообще бессмысленный, т.к. начальное значение захардкожено в коде. Если нужно через код, то нужно проводить выборку $('.count-input').every()... и потом через this выводить

Comment: Можно пожалуйста более подробный кусок кода? Буду очень благодарен, с js у меня траблы

Comment: Просто в html задай для <input readonly name="summ__input" type="text" value="НАЧАЛЬНАЯ_СУМА"> Такую же как и для data-price

Comment: А последний кусок js, который после события 'change' удали

Comment: Все гениальное-просто! :D Понял, все получилось, спасибо огромное за помощь!